# Ghost application error

Tags: ghost

Back story for better understanding:

I have a ghost made by someone else and toady some one I worked with made a new ghost in the same folder with the regular ghost I work with.

I am trying to run the ghost now but get a 1808: Ghost Decompression Error and after aborting I get this message "Application Error 19225: Ghost has detected corruption in the image file. Please perform an integrity check on the image. If this problem persists, contact Symantec Technical Support at http://service.symantec.com"

I would like to now if him making a new ghost could have ruined the old ghost and if not where did my problem come from and how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can store Ghost images in the same folder, as long as they are named differently, just like any other type of file, one should not affect the other.

This error could be caused by a couple different things, such as network connectivity errors or simply a bad image. Are you imaging across a network?

If you hit Abort when the error comes up, you should get another error code, what is that one?

Comment: the image should be fine I have used it before there can't be connectivity problems since it has to be connected to use the ghost the error that comes up is the one I wrote above

Answer (score 0):

Symnantec offers a few thoughts here.  I have had images appear corrupted due to a drive issue so well worth checking.  Howwever, the image may just be corrupt due to another issue and you need to re-image.

When the image file is corrupted, it cannot be repaired. Ghost does not include any features for repairing corrupted image files. You must create a new image file instead.

In some cases, what appears to be a corrupted image file is actually corruption on the source drive (the drive that you created an image of). Before creating a new image file, determine whether the corruption is actually in the image file or whether the corruption is on the source drive. If the corruption is on the source drive, repair the source drive before creating a new image file.

To run the integrity check from Windows (Symantec Ghost 8.x and later)

Run Ghost32.exe. By default this is located at :

C:\Program Files\Symantec\Ghost\Ghost32.exe.

Choose Local > Check > Image File. 
Browse to the image file and click Open. 
Choose Yes to proceed with the integrity check.